# Is there a way to get the derived class to have the base class edit the protected varibales

Tags: c++

So I am experiencing a problem within this class assignment, we are set to code a "Tic Tac Toe" styled game. I thought it would be a good approach to have 2 versions such as original with 3 across and then 4 across. So here is the base class with the problem functions

Here is the minimal that leaves nothing cut out

main.cpp

```
#include "tic_tac_toe.h"
#include "tic_tac_toe_3.h"
#include "tic_tac_toe_4.h"
int main()
{
  std::vector <std::reference_wrapper<Tic_tac_toe>> games;

  string playerOption{ "" };

  bool isRunning{ true }, error{ true };
  int position{ 0 }, playerInt{ 0 };
  char option{ ' ' };



  //main loop
  while (isRunning)
  {

     cout << "Tic Tac Toe game 3 or 4: ";
     cin >> playerInt;

     if (playerInt == 3)
     {
         cout << "Executing tic tac toe 3";
         Tic_tac_toe_3 game3;
         games.push_back(game3);
     }
     else if (playerInt == 4)
     {
         cout << "Executing tic tac toe 4";
         tic_tac_toe_4 game4;
         games.push_back(game4);
     }

     //allows for constant looping to get user to input X or O. So program wont blow up
     while (error)
     {
         cout << "Player 1, X or O: ";
         cin >> playerOption;
         try
         {
             games[games.size() - 1].get().start_game(playerOption); //the .get gets the stored reference
             error = false;
             cout << "\n"; //to add a break in the text
         }
         catch (Error e)
         {
             cout << e.get_message();
         }
     }

     try
     {
         cin >> games[games.size() - 1].get(); //FAIL POINT IMO
         cout << games[games.size() - 1].get();
     }

     catch(Error e)
     {
         cout << e.get_message();
     }
 }
return 0;
}
```

tic_tac_toe.h

```
#include vector

using std::string;

class Tic_tac_toe
{
  public:
    Tic_tac_toe(int size) : pegs(size* size, " ") { } //multiply 3 or 4 by itself for 9 or 16

    void start_game(std::string first_player);
    void mark_board(int position);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Tic_tac_toe& t);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Tic_tac_toe& b);

    string get_player() const { return player; }
    string get_winner() const { return winner; }

protected:

    std::vector<string> pegs; //initializes a vector of x elements with each being a space.

private: //most logic goes within the private functions

    void set_next_player();

    string player;
}
```

tic_tac_toe.cpp

```
{
void Tic_tac_toe::start_game(std::string first_player)
{
    if (first_player == "X" || first_player == "O")
    {
        player = first_player;
        clearBoard();
    }
    else { throw Error("Player must be X or O\n"); }
}

void Tic_tac_toe::mark_board(int position)
{
    if (position < 1 || position > 9)
    {
        throw Error("Position must be 1 to 9.\n");
    }
    else if (player == "")
    {
        throw Error("Must start game first.\n");
    } 
    else
    {
        pegs[(position - 1)] = player; //minus one for the index
        set_next_player();
    }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Tic_tac_toe& b) 
{
    std::cout << "\n"; //formatting purposes
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 9; i += 3) // += 3 for new row
    {
        out << b.pegs[i] + " | " + b.pegs[i + 1] + " | " + b.pegs[i + 2] + "\n";
    }
    return out;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Tic_tac_toe& b)
{
    std::cout << "Pegs size" << b.pegs.size();
    int pos{ 0 };
    std::cout << "Player " << b.get_player() << " enter a position: ";
    in >> pos;
    b.mark_board(pos);

    return in;
}
}
```

tic_tac_toe_4 //4 and 3 are exactly same atm

```
class Tic_tac_toe_4 : public Tic_tac_toe
{

public:

tic_tac_toe_4() : Tic_tac_toe(4) { std::cout << "Passing to constructor"; }

}
```

Comment: Please show the code producing the error message.

Comment: I went and added the location where the error happens

Comment: What did you learn when you used your debugger?  Also, I'm pretty sure the current version of your code doesn't compile.

Comment: Debugger did not really help due to it crashing during runtime, and the code compiles, I just cut out a ton of things to save the thread. I just need to know why the pegs vector is not getting set to proper size

Comment: It's not enough that your original code compiles.  The code that is posted that has had a ton of things cut out of it to save the thread also needs to compile, and reproduce the issue.

Comment: _"Debugger did not really help due to it crashing during runtime"_ Crashing during runtime is exactly what a debugger is there to help you diagnose. In what way did it "not really help"? Did you forget to set a breakpoint on `throw`?

Comment: _"the code compiles, I just cut out a ton of things to save the thread"_ Doesn't save the thread if we can't see the problem. Instead of randomly eliminating pieces of the puzzle, forensically construct a [mcve] so that we can help you.

Comment: I tried my best, I am really sorry for tumbling through this. I am a mess when it comes to stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior, because you are pushing references to local variables such as

```
Tic_tac_toe_3 game3;
```

into `games`. When these variables leave their scope, the references in `games` become invalid and trying to use them later will have undefined behavior.

If you want a container that owns the `Tic_tac_toe` objects, then use

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Tic_tac_toe>>
```

as type instead and create the objects with `std::make_unique`. Then the objects will live until the vector elements owning them are destroyed.

Comment: Thank you so much!!